# Schengen - Change Port of Entry

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas

I applied for a visa at the Belgian embassy for Luxembourg (Belgium handles consular affairs on Luxembourg's behalf in my country). I submitted a flight reservation with Frankfurt as my port of entry into the Schengen area. I also declared on the visa application form that Germany will be the Schengen country of first entry.

Now I'm thinking of flying into Paris or Brussels and taking the train to Luxembourg since it's much cheaper. If I do this, will there be a problem at immigration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such small alterations of your travel plans are routine and allowed without further permission, as long as the visit as a whole is still recognizably the same trip (in terms of purpose and general circumstances) as the one you described in your application.

(As a practical matter, border guards at Paris or Brussels will not even generally have a way to know which precise itinerary you declared in your application).

Comment: I applied for and got a schengen visa from the Austrian embassy and I had declared Vienna as my port of entry. However, by the time I booked my flight I got a hopping flight and my port of entry was Amsterdam. I had no issues at all. I don’t think there should be any issues for train travel too. That’s the way schengen Visa operates.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I pushed through with entering via Paris and I'd like to report that my experience is consistent with that of @BhushanKale — I was let through with no questions asked.